# How to apply the filter function in R correctly?

Tags: r

I cannot apply a simple filter in R, it throws an error that the argument is not found, and I don't know how to solve it. I use imdb database and here is the code:

```
imdb_ratings <- imdb_ratings %>% filter(nrOfWins > 0)
```

The error: `Error in filter(., nrOfWins > 0) : object 'nrOfWins' not found`

Comment: DO you have a column name `nrOfWins`.  R is case sensitive.  Please check if the name is correct

Comment: @akrun Yes, there is such a column.

Comment: can you do `dplyr::filter(nrOfWins > 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we can use `dplyr::filter` explicitly if the function got masked by same function from other packages

```
library(dplyr)
imdb_ratings %>% 
     dplyr::filter(as.numeric(as.character(nrOfWins)) > 0)
```

Comment: Now, it throws out a warning:
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(nrOfWins, 0) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: @use1883 you have a factor column.  Youo could convert to numeric and then do `>` updated the post

Comment: Ok, now it works. Only after I apply the View function it shows no movies, although the data set is not empty after the filter ( I checked using head function)

Comment: @use1883 Is it assigned to a new object?  i.e. `df1 <- imdb_ratings %>% 
     dplyr::filter(as.numeric(as.character(nrOfWins)) > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to load the dplyr package implicitly

Library (dplyr)

Or

dplyr ::filter

Comment: I already havr dplyr loaded, but I guess some other package has the filter function as well (stringr or ggplot2)